# Two location blocks for only two subdomains

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I have the following server block:

```
server {
   server_name *.somedomain.com
   root        /var/www/html/$rootpath/web;
   # etc...
}
```

It caches all folders inside the root, and maps it to the `folder_name.subdomain.com` website.

Right now I have to create two folders there in symfony 2, both should be stagings - one for development, and the second that acts like production (but with development database).

So I have to create two location blocks inside, each catching different domain, so that one domain redirects to app.php, and the second to app_dev.php, etc.

How can I do that? How should the location block look like to catch subdomain? It should look like:

```
server {
   server_name *.somedomain.com;
   root        /var/www/html/$rootpath/web;
   location /development-staging/ {
      index app_dev.php
   }
   location /production-staging/ {
      index app.php
   }
}
```

But it caches `*.somedomain.com/development-staging/` links instead of `development-staging.somedomain.com/`...

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to simply add two additional server blocks

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: you can specify server_name as regex, capture first part of hostname and then use a variable with rewrite, but this way is much worse

Comment: @khernik two different server blocks will be easier to manage than regex

Comment: Two new server blocks is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, for different subdomains better create a separate server block. If for whatever reason you want to define specific behavior for different subdomains in 1 server block, do it like

```
server {
    server_name *.somedomain.com;
    root        /var/www/html/$rootpath/web;

    location / {
        if ( $host = "development-staging.somedomain.com" ) {
            index app_dev.php;
        }
        if ( $host = "production-staging.somedomain.com" ) {
            index app.php;
        }
    }
}
```